# Second digit of the subsections above 10 different color than first

Tags: color, customize

I changed my sections and subsections coloring on latex, however when to 10 and above numbering the second digit returns to black.

here is my code:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{sectsty}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}}
\definecolor{NavyBlue}{RGB}{47, 84, 150}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\renewcommand\thesection{\textcolor{NavyBlue}\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\textcolor{NavyBlue}\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\textcolor{NavyBlue}\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{\color{NavyBlue}{Appendices}}
```

But the result is this after 10 is the first number blue (ergo 1 blue) and 0, 1,... (ergo second digit) black.

I Appreciate the help

Comment: textcolor takes an argument, use `\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\arabic{subsection}}` You would see the same with `\textcolor{NavyBlue}1234` which is  `\textcolor{NavyBlue}{1}234`  just 1 in blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\textcolor{color}{text}` takes two arguments: you have to use curly braces around `\arabic{section}`.

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\arabic{section}}}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! :)